# Передать std::string как параметр функции, принимающей указатель на экземпляр класса

Tags: c++

есть две сферы sphere1, sphere2.
есть консоль принимающая команду, к примеру

```
sphere1.setPos 150 300 0
```

реально ли взять из std::string часть строки "sphere1"
и преобразовать в указатель на экземпляр класса, для того что бы передать его в функцию, как параметр.
что то вроде

```
void setPos( SphereObj* _sphere)
{
    _sphere->setPosition(Vector3(x, y, z));
}

SphereObj convertStringToSphereObj(std::string _str)
{
    тут происходит магия
    return указатель написаный в _str;
}

setPos( convertStringToSphereObj("sphere1"));
```

и не обязательно так, лишь бы была возможность выбирать метод setPos объекта указанного в консоли

Если это возможно, намекните пожалуйста что в гугле искать и реально ли это сделать при помощи LUA или хоть в чём то или как то?

Спасибо за внимание![image: как то так]

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. По строке можно создать соответствующую сферу и вернуть указатель на неё.

Comment: к примеру уже создано 5 сфер, и я хочу поменять позицию к примеру 3-ей сферы через командную строку, проблема в том что командная строка возвращает std::string а функция смены позиции принимает SphereObj* _sphere. и я надеялся что можно их как то подружить

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да не проблема!

Вы должны завести `std::map<std::string, SphereObj*>`, который будет отображать имя сферы на саму сферу.

Тогда волшебный код будет выглядеть очень просто:

```
map<string, SphereObj*> sphereNameMap;

SphereObj* convertStringToSphereObj(string _str)
{
    map<string, SphereObj*>::iterator it = sphereNameMap.find(_str);
    return it != sphereNameMap.end() ? it->second : NULL;
}
```

В случае, если имя неправильное, вернётся `nullptr`.

Ну и вам нужно будет регистрировать все имена:

```
void RegisterSphere(string name, SphereObj* sphere)
{
    if (sphereNameMap.find(name) != sphereNameMap.end())
        throw "this name is already registered";
    sphereNameMap[name] = sphere;
}
```

Comment: `Тогда волшебный код будет выглядеть очень просто:` — вместо `[]` лучше использовать `find()`, чтобы неудачные запросы не добавляли пустых элементов в map.

Comment: @Arhad: Это точно! Если вам не лень, отредактируйте ответ?